# Large numbers messing up?

Tags: lua, numbers

Sorry about the bad title, I couldn't think of anything better. So I was making a function to shorten numbers(1000 to 1k) and here it is.

```
local letters = {
"K",
"M", --I'm too lazy to put more
"B",
"QD",
"QN",
}
local nums = {}

for q=1,#letters do
    local dig = (q*3)+1
    local letter = 1*(10^(dig-1))
    table.insert(nums,#nums+1,letter)
end


function shorten(num)
local len = tostring(num):len()
print(len)
if len>=4 then
    for q=1,#letters do
        local dig = (q*3)+1 --digits the letter is
        if len <= dig+2 then
            local toDo = math.floor(num/nums[q])
            print(nums[q])
            local newNum = toDo..letters[q]
            return newNum
            end
        end
    end
end

print(shorten(178900000000000))
```

And this prints.

```
10 --the length, and the real length of it is 15
1000000000 --the one to divide it
178900B --shortened num
```

I take one zero off of the print(shorten()) and it works fine. And I'm assuming the numbers are too big, or maybe there's a problem with the code. Thank you for reading this.

Comment: `tostring()` might be unexpecting.  For example, for `num = 178900000000000` `tostring(num) = "1.789e+14"`.  More correct way to calculate number of digits: `local len = math.ceil(math.log10(num + .5))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tostring` gives the human-readable string representation, and for a big number like in your example, it uses scientific notation:

```
print(tostring(178900000000000))
```

In Lua 5.2 or lower, the result if `1.789e+14`. In Lua 5.3, because of the newly introduced integer subtype, the result is `178900000000000` as expected, but it would still be broken for even bigger integers.